# How to find $\text{lim}_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}} $

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> I'm trying to determine the limit
> $$
> \text{lim}_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}} 
> $$

Already tried
$$
\bigg( \dfrac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}} \bigg)\times \bigg( \dfrac{\sqrt{2x +3} + \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2x +3} + \sqrt{5}} \bigg)
$$
But it's still impossible.

Without using L'hôpital's rule

Comment: Try L'hopital's rule.

Comment: @JacquesTarr  I can't.

Comment: This sort of no L hospital question is pretty common. Like this one I saw in related questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970985/lim-x-rightarrow-6-frac-sqrtx3-3x-6-without-lh%c3%b4pitals-rule?rq=1 . Only thing that's different is using the rationalization trick for both numerator and denominator. I know you knew about rationalizing the denominator, and I don't want to come off as elitist. At the same time though, I feel like I need to say something for the good of the site as it seems that we have a lot of these sorts of questions

Comment: Yes, the methods in this post answer your question [$\lim_{x\rightarrow 6} \frac{\sqrt{x+3}-3}{x-6}$ without L'Hôpital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970985/lim-x-rightarrow-6-frac-sqrtx3-3x-6-without-lh%c3%b4pitals-rule)

Comment: Carin, what made you believe "it's still impossible"? You should edit your post to include the result of the try you are talking about, and isolate the indeterminate form $\frac{\sqrt x-1}{x-1}$ (the other factors have a non-zero limit). If this still does not enlighten you, look at the proposed duplicate or [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642874), and the many related posts (on the right hand side column of your screen if you work on a PC, or below if on a smartphone). I wish you [the best](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_does_not_kill_me_makes_me_stronger).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you stated, the conjugate of the numerator of the fraction you have is $\sqrt x+1$ and the conjugate of the denominator is $\sqrt {2x+3}+\sqrt {5}\thinspace .$

If these conjugates are both used together, this leads us to the following solution :

$$
\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}} &\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2x +3} + \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2x +3} + \sqrt{5}} \cdot \frac {\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}
=\frac {\left(x-1\right)\left(\sqrt {2x+3}+\sqrt 5\right)}{2\left(\sqrt x+1\right)\left(x-1\right)}\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Note that the solution can also be reached using only the conjugate of the denominator of the fraction. However, we will need an additional mathematical operation such as factorization :

$$
\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}}&=\frac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2x +3} + \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2x +3} + \sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac {\left(\sqrt x-1\right)\left(\sqrt {2x+3}+\sqrt {5}\right)}{2\left(x-1\right)}\\
&=\frac {\left(\sqrt x-1\right)\left(\sqrt {2x+3}+\sqrt {5}\right)}{2\left(\sqrt x-1\right)\left(\sqrt x+1\right)}\\
&=\frac {\sqrt {2x+3}+\sqrt {5}}{2\left(\sqrt x+1\right)}\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Thus, you have :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}}&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac {\sqrt {2x+3}+\sqrt {5}}{2\left(\sqrt x+1\right)}\\
&=\frac {\sqrt{5}}{2}\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Comment: Gooood. Thank you.

Comment: From that answer, I gained one more way to try to calculate limit. Thank you

Comment: @CarinSa You're welcome and thank you. I'm glad the answer worked for you  $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: Better vote to close as a (multi)dupe than duplicate answers.

Comment: This is what we currently call (one of the many) "[abstract dupes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1756)" i.e. giving methods for a very similar example. Moderators like @BillDubuque tirelessly blame such a proliferation, with a link to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508

Comment: @AnneBauval I am aware about abstract dupes. But, in our case,  your dupe link seems technically incorrect. Also: I have strong criticisms/objections to some of the questions that the person you mentioned voted to close.  However, I didn't get into much discussion about it.

Comment: The accepted answer in this "dupe", and [this similar one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1970993/386889), give the same key as your method. I agree there are probably closer duplicates as this one (found by @gist076923) but I don't have the patience and motivation for such a search because it seems to me that such a link should be more useful to the OP than a specific answer, provided they are goodwilling to think and work a little.

Comment: @AnneBauval This is *not* a same key.   Using just conjugate of the numerator doesn't work in this question.

Comment: The key, here and there, *is* the same: multiply (numerator and/or denominator) by conjugate+factorize+cancel. And there are tons of very elementary and repetitive posts on MSE using this method.

Comment: @AnneBauval OP already said, I tried to use conjugate of denominator *or* numerator, which still leads to indeterminate form. Using these conjugates at the same time is very different. I can give you more complicated limit, which conjugates alone, indeed leads to indeterminate form again.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way: by substituting $x=1+y$ the limit becomes
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+y}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{5}y}-1}=
\frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+y}-1}{y}\cdot\frac{\frac{2}{5}y}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{5}y}-1}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}
$$

Comment: Better vote to close as a (multi)dupe than duplicate answers.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see it, by the definition of derivative with

- $f(x)=\sqrt{x} \implies f'(x) = \frac1{2\sqrt x}$
- $g(x)=\sqrt{2x +3} \implies g'(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2x +3}}$

we have

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x} -1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}}=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x} -1}{x-1}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2x +3} - \sqrt{5}}=\frac{f'(1)}{g'(1)}=\frac{\frac12}{\frac1{\sqrt 5}}=\frac{\sqrt 5}2$$

Comment: Better vote to close as a (multi)dupe than duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{2x+3}-\sqrt{5}}
\\ \text{Use L-Hopital now}
\\ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1\cdot2}{2\sqrt{2x+3}}}
\\ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{2x+3}}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} $

ask me any doubts if you've further.

Comment: without L'Hopital's rule...